# How do I click the non-browser area to close the right-click menu generated by JS?

Tags: javascript

I used js to listen to the contextmenu event to create a menu that closes when the mouse clicks on another area.
I found that the Google Cloud Disk's right-click menu can be closed when clicking on a non-page area. How do I do this or what event is being monitored?

Comment: [window.onblur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onblur) maybe? Hard to tell without seeing it. But your dev-tools might expose somewhere all the Events that are attached in your DOM tree.

Comment: Thank you, this is valid. What does it mean to expose the DOM tree event, or do I need to listen to this event when I use it?

Comment: No I meant that from your question we can only guess a response. So for you to find it out, you can check your browser's dev-tools, they generally expose/show which Events have been attached on which elements. In chrome's there is a 'Elements>Event Listeners" tab along with "Element>Styles", on Firefox it's directly in the DOM tree beside each element. From there, you can check what Events are attached and find out if any of these might do what you are seeing.